# How to use AddDbContextPool if all configuration in OnConfiguring method of DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm using PostgreSQL and I have ApplicationDbContext like:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly DatabaseSettings _databaseOptions;
    public ApplicationDbContext() { }
    public ApplicationDbContext(IOptions<DatabaseSettings> databaseOptions)
    {            
        _databaseOptions = databaseOptions.Value;
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasPostgresExtension("citext");
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (_databaseOptions == null)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(_databaseOptions.ConnectionString,
            npgsqlOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
            {
                sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                    maxRetryCount: _databaseOptions.MaxRetryCount,
                    maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_databaseOptions.MaxRetryDelay),
                    errorCodesToAdd: null);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

That context is base for many others. I'm on a way of improvement performance and trying to use context pooling . Docs say to add polling I should:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<EmployeeContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(connection));
```

But I want to store.UseNpgsql and other configs of DbContext in OnConfiguring method. How to achieve that?

Comment: what kind of application you are running? Is it an ASP.NET App?

Comment: yes. asp.net webapi

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Besides the debatable benefits of using it (from the docs: *"has the advantage of saving some of the cost of initialization of DbContext instance"*), the [DbContext pooling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#dbcontext-pooling) is simply not applicable in your scenario, because your context contains *state* which EF Core is unaware of:

```
private readonly DatabaseSettings _databaseOptions;
```

and the [Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#limitations-1) section of the documentation clearly states:

> **Warning!**
>
> Avoid using DbContext Pooling if you maintain your own state (for example, private fields) in your derived DbContext class that should not be shared across requests. EF Core will only reset the state that is aware of before adding a DbContext instance to the pool.

---

There is a reason why `optionsAction` of `AddDbContextPool` is required, while for `AddDbContext` it is optional. It's because of the aforementioned limitation, plus the additional requirement that your `DbContext` derived class must have *single* public constructor with *single* `DbContextOptions` parameter. You can easily see that by fooling the `AddDbContextPool` with passing empty action:

```
services.AddDbContextPool<ApplicationDbContext>(options => { });
```

but then at runtime you'll get `InvalidOperationException` saying

> The DbContext of type 'ApplicationDbContext' cannot be pooled because it does not have a single public constructor accepting a single parameter of type DbContextOptions.

So in order to be eligible for pooling, you have to remove all these

```
private readonly DatabaseSettings _databaseOptions;
public ApplicationDbContext() { }
public ApplicationDbContext(IOptions<DatabaseSettings> databaseOptions)
{            
    _databaseOptions = databaseOptions.Value;
}
```

and add this instead

```
public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options) { }
```

Now you should clearly see why what you are asking is not possible. Your `OnConfiguring` method requires `DatabaseSettings`, but there is no way you could provide it. Hence the `options` must be configured externally.

In other words, your requirements are mutually exclusive, hence there is no solution.

Comment: How I can change it?

Comment: As I mentioned, context like yours is not eligible for context pooling. In other words, simply use `AddDbContext`.

Comment: You can't if you need these `DatabaseSettings`. Context pooling requires db context  having single public constructor with `DbContextOptions` (or `DbContextOptions<TContext>`) parameter. So you have to remove the `DatabaseSettings` parameter, but then you won't know how to configure your context inside `OnConfiguring`, so it has to be configured externally. As you can see, the problem is not the `AddDbContextPool` call (it can easily be called with empty action), but the combination of your requirements, which has no solution.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this doesn't have a solution - as much as anything really. @Pr.Dumbledor, while @Ivan Stoev is right about everything, I'd say it depends whether you can compromise and set the `DatabaseSettings` options externally, where and when do you create the db context, do you just check if the `DatabaseSettings` options don't exist (are passed to the constructor) and create an inmemory instead of a real Psql db connection? Are the `MaxRetryCount` and `MaxRetryDelay` always the same?

Comment: @eja But they contain the most important information - the connection string. Without that basically there is nothing that can be done in `OnConfiguring`. And that's exactly what OP wants at the end the post - *"But I want to store.UseNpgsql and other configs of DbContext in OnConfiguring method. How to achieve that?"* This sounds like "no solution" to me :)

Comment: @IvanStoev I see.. In any case, the comments above "how i can change it" and "how to change it for context pooling" just made me think. I agree, the only way to use context pooling, is if OP could move the  `DatabaseSettings` and `OnConfiguring` override out of `ApplicationDbContext`. I'm not sure if I'm missing something, can't he check for the connection string, and whether to create an inmemory or Psql context within/at `services.AddDbContextPool()`? And yes, only if removing `OnConfiguring` is acceptable..? @Pr.Dumbledor

Answer (score 2):

As an addendum to [@Ivan Stoev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55917552/6317679), should anyone need a way of creating reusable logic for an options instance that is then used to initialize a `PooledDbContext`'s configuration, they can take the following approach:

As Ivan clarified, your `DbContext` itself **must** have only a single constructor that takes in the `DbContextOptions<TContext>`. However, there's nothing stopping you from creating your own independent `ConfigurationBuilder` in the `Action<DbContextOptions<TContext>>` you pass to the `AddDbContextPool()` method. For example...

```cs
public class Program
{
    static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((host, services) => {
                // Build DatabaseSettings from config just like IOptions<T> would.
                var config = host.Configuration;
                var settings = new DatabaseSettings();
                config.Bind(nameof(DatabaseSettings), settings);

                // Use settings to configure pool.
                services.AddPooledDbContextFactory<EmployeeContext>(optionsBuilder => {
                    if (settings.ConnectionString == null)
                    {
                        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(settings.ConnectionString,
                        npgsqlOptionsAction: sqlOptions =>
                        {
                            sqlOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure(
                                maxRetryCount: settings.MaxRetryCount,
                                maxRetryDelay: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(settings.MaxRetryDelay),
                                errorCodesToAdd: null);
                        });
                    }
                });
                
                // Add example scoped configuration options
                services.AddOptions<MyOptions>();

                // Initialize each DbContext upon request
                services.AddScoped<EmployeeContext>(srv => {
                    var factory = srv.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<EmployeeContext>>();
                    var snapshot = srv.GetRequiredService<IOptionsSnapshot<MyOptions>>();
                    var ctx = factory.CreateDbContext();

                    // ctx.SomeProperty = snapshot.Value.SomeProperty;
                    return ctx;
                });
            }).Build();
    }
}
```

If you really **do** need per-instance `DbContext` configuration when using a pool, then you can follow the documentation's recommendation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/advanced-performance-topics?tabs=with-di%2Cwith-constant#managing-state-in-pooled-contexts).

By accessing the `DbContext` instance through the service collection and using a registered factory method that instantiates the `DbContext` from the pooled `IDbContextFactory<TContext>`, you can then do any sort of initialization hand-off you need for code that uses your `DbContext`. This is especially useful when combined with `IOptionsSnapshot<T>` or `IOptionsMonitor<T>` to apply real-time configuration data to this initialization process.